# Build rViz on top of Melodic

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build rViz on top of melodic; but think I have some of the setup incorrect.
I have cloned rViz to

```
/home/brent/rosbuild_ws/src/rviz
```

I then ran

```
cd /home/brent/rosbuild_ws
rosws init . /opt/ros/melodic
rosdep install rviz
rosmake rviz
```

I see the below output which is generated in under 1 second; so I don't think anything is actually getting built.

Any tips on what is wrong with my setup would be most appreciated.

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/ccdfd95294b794ad6c9bc7aea022d655

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360618/build%C2%A0rviz-on-top-of-melodic/) by [bgraysea](https://answers.ros.org/users/56768/bgraysea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I then ran
>
> ```
> cd /home/brent/rosbuild_ws
> rosws init . /opt/ros/melodic
> rosdep install rviz
> rosmake rviz
> ```

RViz has not been a `rosbuild` package for quite some time now.

You'll need to use Catkin to build RViz in a Catkin workspace.

In general the use of `rosbuild` has been deprecated for a long time. See also [wiki/rosbuild](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild).

I would recommend you always assume you have to use Catkin these days, *unless* the instructions specifically tell you otherwise.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bgraysea](https://answers.ros.org/users/56768/bgraysea/) on 2020-08-31**:
Ok great
And it did seem strange to me; but I was following from http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide Section 2.2 `Build from source` Are there updated build instructions anywhere that you are aware of?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-31**:
I can't point you to anything RViz specific right now, but #q252478 should provide generic how-to-build-a-package-from-source-with-catkin instructions.